# The type initializer for 'Module' threw an exception

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Having a **c++/cli** project and it's a *windows application*. In debug mode we didn't have any problems but after taking it to release mode this error start up. I searched and found some forum-answers but couldn't help me solve this problem.

Please help me ....

*Error :*

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module
```

**Additional information**: The type *initializer* for '**Module**' threw an exception.

Comment: i think it will be better to post some code around the "module" initializer.

Answer (score 5):

In a C++/CLI project, the `<Module>` class is special (note the angle brackets).  It is a hidden managed class that the compiler generates to give all of your functions that are not methods of a class a safe home.  Required because the CLR does not support free functions like C++ does.

The type initializer for `<Module>` is extra special, it runs *very* early at the start of the program.  That's where the CRT gets started and any static objects in your code get initialized.

So the basic diagnostic you have is that the initialization of a static object in your code failed.  That this happens at startup *and* only happens in the Release build is very, very painful.  The debugger doesn't let you step through this code and of course you don't have good debug info to start with in the Release build.  With some luck, the root cause is a C++ or SEH exception that didn't get handled.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkboxes.  The debugger will stop when the exception is thrown.

Comment: `<Module>` is more than just hidden -- it has very special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine where the application is running has all the required dlls??

I strongly believe that you are missing some interops in the local directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it got fixed after I install Visual Studio 2015 Redistributable **x64** and **x86**.

Install VS C++ 2015 Redistributable (both [x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52685) & [x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145))

Make sure you install both the x64 and x86 versions.

Hope this should fix the issue.